# iMac 2011 with MacBook Air 2010

Tags: imac, macbook-pro, thunderbolt

I have iMac 2011 with ThunderBolt and MacBook Air 2011 with Mini DisplayPort. Can I connect them with a ThunderBolt cable? It is for work in Photoshop on two displays. Thanks!

Comment: Is the MBA 2010 or 2011?

Answer (score 2):

To use Target Display mode with a Thunderbolt equipped iMac you need another Thunderbolt equipped Mac and a Thunderbolt cable [emphasis is mine]:

> iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011) and iMac (27-inch, Mid 2011) support Target Display Mode via Thunderbolt to Thunderbolt cable (2 m) when the source is **another Thunderbolt-equipped computer**.

Source: [iMac (Mid 2011): Target Display Mode does not work with Mini DisplayPort cable](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3775)

If your MacBook Air has Mini DisplayPort then it will not work. More [here](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.7/en/mh30822.html) about what options *will* work.